# Group Query in Rails involving associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, group-by

I have two tables (and associated models) in my Rails database with a one-to-many relationship.

```
billable_totals
---------------
id
project_id
adjusted_amount

projects
---------
id
project_type
```

The associated models are BillableTotal and Project with the following relationships:

```
BillableTotal belongs_to Project
Project has_many BillableTotals
```

I want to do a group query which outputs the project_type from projects table and the sum of adjusted_amount from billable_totals grouped by project_type.  I am running into all sorts of problems.  Both activerecord and Postgres keep complaining.  Please advise on how to structure this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
Project.joins(:billable_totals).group(:project_type).sum('billable_totals.adjusted_amount')
```

I could at least run a query on that format in my own project and get reasonable results.

Comment: Many thanks.  Works.  Follow up question.  How can approach it from other direction? i.e., something like BillableTotal.joins(:project) ...etc.  I tried that for an hour and got nowhere.

Comment: `BillableTotal.joins(:project).group('projects. project_type').sum(: adjusted_amount)`  should work I think. Writing this from the wrong computer so I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks again.  The first one is correct, i.e., BillableTotal.joins(:project)... since it is a one-to-many relationship.  BillableTotal.joins(:projects) throws error